# Can I make my sensitivity lower?

Tags: 18.04

I was wondering if I can make my sensitivity lower than what you can in the settings. I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my main gaming pc and the sensitivity won't go low enough for what i need. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867648/how-to-decrease-mouse-sensitivity-beyond-settings-limit

Comment: What sensitivity? Mouse? Pointer speed? Scroll speed? Something else? Got to give us more information.